# laravel store old data in textfield

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

i am working on laravel project where i am passing data from other page. it get the data and put it in the field but when i refresh the field it always there i guess laravel store this data some where(cookies). how to remove this feature.

this is my text field.

```
 <input id="ben_account_num" type="number" class="form-control" name="ben_account_num"value="<?php if(isset($get_account)){ echo $get_account; }else{ echo "";} ?>" required >
```

i have also try to reset form but it also give me old value

```
$("#formId")[0].reset();
```

Comment: Please hard refresh or php artisan cache:clear

Comment: i want to remove this old data store feature from this form

Comment: seems your controller pass data on every request, not old input problem. may be you should show how you are passing data to this view and its controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`autocomplete`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) to off to prevent browsers from retaining input values on refresh.

**Try:**

```
 <input id="ben_account_num" type="number" class="form-control" name="ben_account_num"value="<?php if(isset($get_account)){ echo $get_account; }else{ echo "";} ?>" required autocomplete="off">
```

Or

**Add this to the form itself:**

```
<form autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: still getting the old data

Comment: still the old result

Comment: i guess laravel storing some where

Comment: @SherazKhan post the controller code where you return this view page

Comment: thanks bro i have solve it with jquery the problem was that laravel store this variable in cookies and get it from there i clear the variable

Comment: @SherazKhan If it helped you, Please accept the answer